# startswith() function help needed in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Name Column in Dataframe in which there are Multiple names.

DataFrame

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['Brailey, Mr. William Theodore Ronald', 'Roger Marie Bricoux',
                            "Mr. Roderick Robert Crispin",
                            "Cunningham"," Mr. Alfred Fleming"]})`
```

OUTPUT

```
   Name
0  Brailey, Mr. William Theodore Ronald
1                   Roger Marie Bricoux
2           Mr. Roderick Robert Crispin
3                            Cunningham
4                    Mr. Alfred Fleming
```

I wrote a row classification function, like if I pass a row/name it should return output class

```
mus = ['Brailey, Mr. William Theodore Ronald', 'Roger Marie Bricoux', 'John Frederick Preston Clarke']
def classify_role(row):
    if row.loc['name'] in mus:
        return 'musician'
```

Calling a function

```
is_brailey = df['name'].str.startswith('Brailey')
print(classify_role(df[is_brailey].iloc[0]))
```

Should show 'musician'
But output is showing different class I think I am writing something wrong here in `classify_role()`
Must be this row
`if row.loc['name'] in mus:`

Summary:
I am in need of a solution if I put first name of a person in `startswith()` who is in `musi` it should return `musician`

Comment: Couldn't replicate what you describe. I copy pasted your code, just changing the "Name" to "name" when you are creating the dataframe: https://repl.it/repls/DeafeningEffectiveOpenlook

Comment: can u post an expected output dataframe?

Comment: I am having a problem in `if row.loc['name'] in mus:` line of  
`def classify_role(row)` data frame is already added and I change the "Name" to "name" it was atypo

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: If want test if values exist in lists you can create dictionary and test membership by [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
mus = ['Brailey, Mr. William Theodore Ronald', 'Roger Marie Bricoux',
       'John Frederick Preston Clarke']
cat1 = ['Mr. Alfred Fleming','Cunningham']

d = {'musician':mus, 'category':cat1}

for k, v in d.items():
    df.loc[df['Name'].isin(v), 'type'] = k
print (df)
                                   Name      type
0  Brailey, Mr. William Theodore Ronald  musician
1                   Roger Marie Bricoux  musician
2           Mr. Roderick Robert Crispin       NaN
3                            Cunningham  category
4                    Mr. Alfred Fleming  category
```

---

Your solution should be changed:

```
mus = ['Brailey, Mr. William Theodore Ronald', 'Roger Marie Bricoux',
          'John Frederick Preston Clarke']
def classify_role(row):
     if row in mus:
        return 'musician'

df['type'] = df['Name'].apply(classify_role)
print (df)
                                   Name      type
0  Brailey, Mr. William Theodore Ronald  musician
1                   Roger Marie Bricoux  musician
2           Mr. Roderick Robert Crispin      None
3                            Cunningham      None
4                    Mr. Alfred Fleming      None
```

---

You can pass values in tuple to [`Series.str.startswith`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html), solution should be expand to match more categories by dictionary:

```
d = {'musician': ['Brailey, Mr. William Theodore Ronald'],
     'cat1':['Roger Marie Bricoux', 'Cunningham']}

for k, v in d.items():
    df.loc[df['Name'].str.startswith(tuple(v)), 'type'] = k
print (df)
                                   Name      type
0  Brailey, Mr. William Theodore Ronald  musician
1                   Roger Marie Bricoux      cat1
2           Mr. Roderick Robert Crispin       NaN
3                            Cunningham      cat1
4                    Mr. Alfred Fleming       NaN
```

Comment: I want this to be done in `classify_role()`defination like I used if condition that checks through `in`.
Because there are multiple classes and I am automating it through `classify_role()`

Comment: @Swati - I think you want first or second solution, please check edit.

Comment: could we just change this in my code `if row.loc['name'] in mus:` line to get to the solution?

Comment: And how would I achieve that by just changing this `if row.loc['name'] in mus:`
bcz there are multiple classes I dont want to mess with other

Comment: @Swati - it is wrong, close is `if row['name'] in mus` and `df['type'] = df.apply(classify_role, axis=1)`